# Is it true that if $Y$ is infinite and $|X|<|Y|$, then $|Y^X| \leq |Y|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that for any finite $n$, $|\mathbb{N}^n| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$, in other words, the set of all $n$-tuples of natural numbers is no bigger than the set of natural numbers and $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{R}|$, the set of sequences of real numbers is no bigger than the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|X|=\aleph_0,\,|Y|=\aleph_1$ then $|Y|\le2^{\aleph_0}$ in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so that $|Y^X|=2^{\aleph_0}$, giving a counterexample in $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$. More generally, in $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg GCH}$ some ordinal $\alpha$ satsifies $2^{\aleph_\alpha}>\aleph_{\alpha+1}$, so $|X|=\aleph_\alpha,\,|Y|=\aleph_{\alpha+1}\le2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ provides a similar counterexample. By contrast, in $\mathsf{ZFC+GCH}$ ordinals $\alpha<\beta$ satisfy $|X|=\beth_\alpha,\,|Y|=\beth_\beta,\,|Y^X|=|Y|$. Therefore, the conjecture is equivalent in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to $\mathsf{GCH}$.